# Unmap and map network drive using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a script in which i need to unmap a drive and store its path and then remap it.
I know that i can find that the drive is mapped and delete it using

```
if exist z:\ (
    net use z: /delete
)
```

When I do  `net use Z:` i get

```
Local name        Z:
Remote name       \\networkpath\to\drive
Resource type     Disk
Status            OK
# Opens           0
# Connections     1
The command completed successfully.
```

I want to use the remote name to remap the drive at the end of my script. Ps suggest how to get the remote name so that i can do `net use z: \\networkpath\to\drive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims= " %%a in ('net use z:') do if "%%a"=="name" set "remotename=%%b"
echo %remotename%
```

should extract that data

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %A in ('net use Z: ^| findstr /c:"Remote name"') do echo %A %B
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %A in ('net use Z: ^| findstr /c:"Remote name"') do echo %B
```

Both of the above handles spaces in the shared path.

See `for /?` and `findstr /?`

Comment: For use in a batch-file this should be %%A and %%B.